# How to set dynamic height for my list view up to my botton navigation bar?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of items and and I want to set the height of container that contain this items up to my button navigation bar and I need to be dynamical for all device.
[My list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CocBr.png)

```
    SizedBox(
        child: ListView.builder(
         scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
         itemCount: state.stories.length,
         itemBuilder: (context, index) {
           return ListItemWidget(
              story: state.stories[index]);
                            }),
                      )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the body of a scaffold in a Container.

This container can have the height of the Screen *0.95 (all except appbar).

Then you put as child an expanded widget and as child of that the list view.